# issue adding privilege to pgSQL table

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

Based on what I've read in the "Examples" section [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html), I think the code below should allow me to alter my tables so that all current and future tables will be read/write.

```
$sql = "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;";
$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(); // <-- LINE 14
$sql1 = "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALTER ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;";
$sth1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
$sth1->execute();
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "DEFAULT" LINE 1: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT
>   SELECT ON TA... ^' in .... on line 14

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: If you're using emulated prepares, try executing the statement without preparing it, using `$pdo->exec($sql)`.

Comment: @Denis When I remove that I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`.

Comment: $thomas: not `$stmt->execute()`. `$pdo->exec()`: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php (I think depesz has the correct answer, that said. I was merely wondering if it might be a bug in PDO's emulated prepare parser or something to that effect.)

Comment: @Denis Yeah, sorry..misread that. I get the same error as the first time when I try `$pdo->exec($sql);`. Thanks.

Comment: Please **always** include your PostgreSQL version (`SELECT version()`) in questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you're running the query on too old PostgreSQL. ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES was added in 9.0.

Comment: Thanks. Seems I'm running `PostgreSQL 8.4.13`. Seems like we just upgraded.

Comment: 8.4 is pretty old - 4 years. 9.0 is almost 3 years old.

Comment: My server guy told me that 8.4 is the highest that cPanel supports. Which I suppose means that if I installed a higher version, I'd not be able to continue to use phpPgAdmin..

Comment: You can always install phpPgAdmin yourself. If some software (cPanel) doesn't let you use newer version of database, it's perfectly valid reason to stop using this software (cPanel, not Pg).